# Finding all subproperties using Jena

Tags: java, jena

I was trying to find all subproperties (1 and more level) for given property using [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntProperty.html#listSubProperties--) API in Java. Below is part of schema file.

**Schema file**

```
<!-- http://www.inmindcloud.com/application/schema.owl#calculation -->

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&as;calculation">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">calculation</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:comment rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">This is comment</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="&as;businessData"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

**Java Code**

```
private static OntModel enhanceCalculableProperties(final OntModel model)
{
        final OntProperty businessDataProperty = model.getOntProperty(Schema.businessData.getURI());
        final OntProperty calculationProperty = model.getOntProperty(Schema.calculation.getURI());

        final List<? extends OntProperty> businessDataSubProperties = businessDataProperty.listSubProperties(false)
            .toList();
        final List<? extends OntProperty> calculationSubProperties = calculationProperty.listSubProperties().toList();

        final boolean containsCalculationProperty = businessDataSubProperties.contains(calculationProperty);
        final boolean containsSubProperties = businessDataSubProperties.containsAll(calculationSubProperties);

        System.out.println(containsCalculationProperty); // true
        System.out.println(containsSubProperties); // false

    return model;
}
```

As per the documentation it should return all subProperties, which is not the case.

You can see from above code, **containsSubProperties** is **false**.

Any suggestions to fix this will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you set up the OntModel? I'm not quite sure but I think if inference is not enabled by the underlying model, then methods like listSubProperties will only list direct subproperties, and not the inferred indirect values.

Comment: @cygri There is no reasoner or inference in my model. Everything is asserted by default.

Comment: the property `business` has sub-property `calculation`, and the property `calculation` has super-property `business`, right?. According to the given RDF (and please use turtle next time) there is no any (direct or indirect) sup-properties for `calculation`. What did you expect?

Comment: @ssz Its the other way around. See schema file shown above.

Comment: well, the schema shows `<calculation> rdfs:subPropertyOf <business>`, yes ? where is super and sub property in this statement ?

Comment: @Pratik Can you find out what sub-properties of `calculation` are missing from `calculationSubProperties`, and show their definition from the schema file?